# Problem in jQuery updating form (PHP)

Tags: php, jquery

I want to edit field with jquery dialog box, but not able to find problem.
I have fetch data from table. And jquery dialog box only show when i click top edit button, second edit button not working.

Thanks

```
<?php 
include "db.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Registration Form</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#overview h2 { border: 1px dashed gray; padding: 10px; background-color: #ffc;
    color: black; font-size: medium; margin: 10px 0;
}
#footer { font-family: sans-serif; color: #888 }
#domMessage { padding: 10px; }
div.blockMe { padding: 30px; margin: 30px; border: 10px solid #ccc; background-color: #ffd }
#question { background-color: #ffc; padding: 10px; }
#question input { width: 4em }

#demoTable { border: 1px solid #ddd }
#demoTable tr.odd { background-color: #efe }
#demoTable th { padding: 15px; background-color: #ffa }
#demoTable td { padding: 15px; vertical-align: top }
#tallContent h1 { margin: 15px }

#twitter { float:right; right: 20px; margin: 0 15px 15px 15px }
#twitter a { text-decoration: none; font-family: arial }
#twitter img { border: none; float: left }
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo1').click(function() {
        $.blockUI({ message: $('#loginForm') });

    });
    $('#close').click(function() {
        $.unblockUI();


    });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<fieldset>
 <legend><strong>Labs:</strong></legend></fieldset>
<table align="center" width="80%"> 
<tr><td align="right" ><a href="pt.php"><button>+</button></a></td></td></tr>
</table>
<table align="center"  border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="80%" bordercolor="#CCCCCC">


    <tr style="background-image:url(img/tr.png);">
    <th>ID:</th>
    <th>Date of Report:</th>
    <th>Name:</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    </tr>

<?php
$str="select * from `labs` order by `id` DESC ";
$rs=mysql_query($str);
?>
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['id'];?> </td>
<td><?php echo $row['date'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['name'];?> </td>
<td align="center"><button id="demo1">Edit</button>
<a href="delte.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><button>X</button></a></td>


</tr>
<?php
}
?>
     <div id="loginForm" style="display:none;width:300px;height:200px;background-color:#b0c4de;margin:20px;padding:30px;">

            <p><label>Date of Report:</label><input type="text" name="demo1" /></p>
            <p><label>Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="demo1" /></p>
            <a href="#" id="close">Update</a>
        </div>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

***edit.php***

```
<?php 
include "db.php";
$action=$_POST['action'];
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];

$str="select * from `labs` where id='$id'";

$rs=mysql_query($str);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Labs</title>

</head>

<body>
<table align="center" width="75%" border="0">
<form name="frm" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Labs:</legend>
    <tr><td><strong>Date of Report:</strong></td><td ><input type="text" size="10" name="date" value="<?php echo $row['date']?>" />dd/mm/yyyy </td></tr><br />
    <tr><td><strong>Name:</strong></td><td > <input type="text"  size="30" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name']?>" /></td></tr><br />

    <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="insert" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
  </fieldset>
  <tr><td colspan="2"><font color="#FF0000"><?php $msg=$_REQUEST['msg'];
  echo $msg;
  ?></font></td></tr>

</form>
</table>


</body>
</html>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['insert']));
{


$date=$_POST['date'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
if(!$name==" ")
{
exit(0);
}
$sql="UPDATE `labs` SET  `date` =  '$date',
`name` =  '$name' WHERE  `labs`.`id` =$id LIMIT 1 ";

mysql_query($sql);

}
?>
```

Comment: Hi there [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/). I feel in deep pain now that I saw your code...

Comment: I can't help you if you don't help yourself by starting to learn proper code practices. You are doing everything WRONG!

Comment: When Shef is trying to say is that you have a SQL injection vulnerability. Where you're using `$_REQUEST['id']` and `$_POST['action']` in `edit.php` you need to sanitise those variables, because otherwise nefarious users could make your script execute nasty SQL commands. But seems Shef prefers take the "arse" approach of telling you that. Research SQL injection and you're half-way there because remember: knowing is half the battle!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a mess, but rather than tear it down to the foundations and build it again, I'll just supply a quick solution.

In the main file, change

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo1').click(function() {
        $.blockUI({ message: $('#loginForm') });

    });
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.demoButton').click(function() {
        $.blockUI({ message: $('#loginForm') });

    });
```

and, change

```
<td align="center"><button id="demo1">Edit</button>
<a href="delte.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><button>X</button></a></td>
```

to

```
<td align="center"><button class="demoButton">Edit</button>
<a href="delte.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><button>X</button></a></td>
```

IDs have to be unique within a page. As you have the button element within the `while()` loop, and it retains the same ID, this is a problem, and jQuery will only bind to the first element it finds with the specified ID.

Classes, on the other hand, can occur multiple times throughout a page. So we change the attribute from `id="..."` to `class="..."`, and the jQuery selector from the ID to the Class.